# CSS not behaving, 2 columns and 1 row spanning both columns

Tags: html, css

I never have any luck with CSS. I have a dialog which is displayed when the user clicks a button. In this div there is an image, and 2 other divs (containing more elements).

It should all look like the following.
[image: Photoshop Concept]

The second columns which contained "Applied Filters" should be on the right of the image, and span the width between the end of the image, and the end of the main container. But instead, it has gone under the image.

[See JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKdfG/embedded/result/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="filter_dialog">
    <img src="data/images/20140206/0/emma-watson-hot-43.jpg" width="550px" />
    <div class="applied_filters">
        <p>Applied Filters</p>
    </div>
    <div class="filters">dsadsa</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter_dialog {
    background-color:#333333;
    border:solid 1px #666666;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:15px;
}
.filter_dialog img {
    border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
}
.applied_filters {
    float:left;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    width:100%;
}
.filters {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If it's being pushed down but you've floated them, it means something is too wide and is pushing it down.

Comment: http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~szreder/css.gif

Comment: Why do you have applied_filters with a float left? It should be 'right'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set a fixed width on the two filters divs. I'd suggest wrapping them in one `div` with the fixed width, set to `float: right`, and then float the image left.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define widths on the `.filter-image` and `.applied-filter` DIVs.  See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2EUn/) for an example:

```
<div class="filter-dialog">
    <div class="filter-container">
        <div class="filter-image">
            <img src="http://aerodesign.okstate.edu/projects/kittyhawk%20page/A_dragon.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="applied-filters">applied</div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-options">options</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% width means 100% width of the nearest relative/absolute positioned **PARENT** so no that is not the way to do it.

Solutions:

**A)** The width of the "Applied Filters" and the image-width are always the same => add it a proper width so it could fit next to each other. could be done like:

```
img{ max-width: 75% } /*or proper px*/
.filterClass{ width: 24%; } /*or proper px*/
```

**B)** The image size is not fixed => use a javascript framework like jQuery to count the current image size and change the `.filterClass`'s width like `$('.filterClass').css('width', countedWidth);`